# It is necessary to activate zipalign in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-gradle-plugin

it is necessary to activate zipalign in gradle or it is automatically activated without writting nothing in gradle build file?

I can't find nothing in documentation: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

They only mention zipalign if you sign your apks with jarsigner but i am using gradle instead of jarsigner..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. You can run `./gradlew -m :app:assembleDebug` to see that `zipalignDebug` is a dependency of `assembleDebug`.

You get both APKs in `app/build/outputs/apk`.

Comment: and what happens with assembleRelease? should i add zipaling to gradle?

Comment: If you set up the signing config for the release build type (as described in the page you linked to), assembleRelease will automatically call zipalignRelease.